# How can I make the DNN edit control edit the right item?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc app that has a listing and a details view.

I have two templates, one for listing, and one for details. Listing has "list" enabled. "Details" does not.

The details view is set up so that when there's a query string of '/details/', it shows a single property details.

When a user clicks on something in the listing, it brings them to the details view. The details view uses the details template and the URL is like /properties/details/my-nice-property.

When the Content Editor goes to edit the property using the **DNN black and white pencil icon**, it edits the first item in the list, not the property that they're viewing.

Is there a way that I can make it so that the DNN edit icon edits the property that the content editor is viewing?

I realize that this seems like such a minor issue and that the content editor should be editing using the 2sxc controls, not the DNN controls. But is there a way to make sure that the DNN control edits the specific property we're viewing, and not just the first item in the list?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the default Dnn Action dropdown menu, I don't think you can control that. 2sxc just hooks it up to edit the first default item.

What we do instead on detail pages/views is to explicitly put a nice but edit button on the page. Here is an example using Bootstrap. Basically all we are doing is a custom 2sxc on-click event that calls back in to Dnn popping the edit interface for the EntityId we give it.

Since there is a nice big Edit Me button on the page, it (hopefully) negates the user expecting or needing go to that Dnn Action menu. The example below even has a FontAwesome icon. This assumes you've already got the right article in a variable.

```
@if(Edit.Enabled) 
{
  <a class="btn btn-secondary text-white mb-1"
    @* this is a great example of how to make a different button than the normal 2sxc hover-blue-circles *@
    onclick='$2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).manage.run({"action": "edit", "entityId": @detail.EntityId})'>
    <i class="fas fa-edit mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Edit: @detail.EntityTitle</span>
  </a>
}
```

So something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually never knew how to make an explicit edit button like this. Super useful.

Answer (score 1):

All that having been said, I do believe there is a way to do this, but you have to use all the 2sxc features and do less in code. I prefer a) to do it in code in my view. I get the article slug from the QueryString and lookup the right article, etc. and b) I also prefer my editors not be in Dnn's edit state, I try to avoid ever having them need to know there is a Dnn Action Menu dropdown.

But you could instead do the same thing using a 2sxc Query that would use a Filter to match your slug (UrlKey). Then the correct item "Default" stream feeding to the view will (or should be) hooked up to the Dnn Action Edit menu item. So after you create the Query, the only extra step is in your View, scroll down and expand the `Data for this Template` section and select the Query that will now do the work of matching the UrlKey to the article and selecting it as "the one."

[image]

Comment: I totally agree about simply teaching clients to use the blue edit controls instead of going into Edit Mode. I only posed the question because 1 particular client (who is experienced in DNN and teaches her clients how to edit in DNN asked about it). I'll just instruct them to update their process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron I believe @Jeremy is right - if the Query is used to filter the data before the view is loaded, then edit will probably do what you expect.

If you filter in in code, it probably won't.